# How to recognise and extract audio feature in Android

Tags: android, audio, fft, speech-recognition, feature-extraction

In the Netherlands hundreds of people get injured during new years eve. Every year a few dozen people loose an eye because of firework accidents. The majority of the victims never sets of fireworks themselves but are just at the wrong place at the wrong time.

I would like to develop an Android app which can identify the sound made by fireworks using the microphone of a smartphone. In a central database the location (via the GPS of the smartphone) and time of the firework detection is stored from which a map of dangerous areas is created. Law enforcement agencies could use this map to patrol more often in certain areas at certain time of the day.

If a large group of people will start using the app, it should be possible to very precisely find the location of the sound source using triangulation. Since the perpetrators (usually a group of youngsters) continuously produce explosion sounds it should be possible to monitor the path they walk and predict their next location.

My questions is, which [audio feature extraction software](http://www.audiocontentanalysis.org/software/) would be most suitable to use in this case.

Answer (score 1):

A good library would be [musicg](https://code.google.com/p/musicg/), because you can read the amplitude and frequency. It's open source too.
Good luck - veel succes!